# Vue 3 Add Wrapper Around Each Child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a form component as the following:

```
<form-component>
    <text-component name="test1" />
    <select-component name="test2" />
</form-component>
```

I need FormComponent to be able to apply a wrapper div around each child

From the above code, FormComponent output should be something like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <text-component name="test1" />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <select-component name="test2" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to wrap each child in a slot like that. What if the parent changes the slot content, which is a perfectly valid thing to do? I imagine changing the markup of the parent (which is what you'd be doing) could cause more problems than you're trying to solve

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to have FormComponent style the form (one text box per row, 2 text boxes per row, label above the text box, label beside text box etc...)

Any suggestions?


Thanks!

Comment: I know what you're trying to achieve, I'm saying you can't achieve it inside `<form-component>` component code, it needs to be done ... oh, like the answer below

Comment: I have seen this done in some packages, for example Formulate and FormKit

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to go about it:

```js
const formChildren = [{
  name: 'test1',
  is: TextComponent  
}, {
  name: 'test2',
  is: SelectComponent  
}]
```

```html
<form-component :children="formChildren" />
```

**FormComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <div 
      v-for="(child, index) in children"
      :key="index"
      class="mb-3"
    >
      <component v-bind="child" />
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
<script setup>
defineProps(['children'])
</script>
```

---

And here's a [working demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) of the suggestion you made in the comments, to loop through contents of `$slots.default()`.

If you prefer writing your logic in template syntax, that's the way to go, I see nothing wrong with it.

I personally prefer the first approach, as my tendency is (in general), to limit the template syntax to minimum. Keeping components in object or map structures allows me to have granular control and automate tasks such as:

- validation
- event management
- applying dynamic default values coming from configuration objects
- handling browser/device quirks

My preference probably comes from having worked a lot in config driven environments, where the business logic is typically stored in objects. There's nothing wrong with writing it in template syntax, though but, overall, I find it limiting.

Comment: Thanks, although that's a working solution, but I'm trying to have a more cleaner way of writing complex forms, for that reason I think having the elements inside the form components (like many libraries does) would be ideal.

I thought about a possible solution which seems to be working, by looping through default slots and rendering vnode:

```<template v-for="(vnode, index) in $slots.default()" :key="index"><component :is="vnode"/></template>
```
However, I haven't tested this solution extensively and not sure yet if it's ideal.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you asked the wrong question. I answered the question you asked. How do you define *"ideal"* in this case?

Comment: I've added a working example of what you suggested. It works and I don't see any problem with the pattern. It just picks up whatever you place in the default slot.

Comment: One potential issue is if you need to add html tags inside the form component, adding the schema as prop to the form is great but it limit the use case when you need to add other html tags inside the form while building it. The question is how to wrap html elements around vue components children.

Comment: The way I handled that when I needed it was to create a custom component which handled the exception(s) (e.g: render a disclamer, render images). But the root level (the form) didn't need to know it's not an actual input (the custom component shared the form element interface - it validated, etc..). The interface was nestable, so I could build layouts and stepped forms with it. All groups of form elements extended the form element interface (basically being valid when all their children were valid)

Comment: Besides, when nesting objects you actually have a lot more freedom than with template syntax. For example, I was able to change the DOM layout and form organisation depending on device on the fly, just from the config object. The DOM was resulting from the business logic, it wasn't dictating it. The same control could render a different type of element based on whether the device was touch based or pointer based, where it made sense.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are adding sub schema inside the form? ```<form-component><form-group :schema=“{...}”/></form-component>``` correct? If so are you suggesting using Vue 3 composition to share the interface with form and form group? Thanks,

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you have example or any sample. Thanks!

Comment: I don't. First of all, it was developed under contract so it's that company's, not mine. Secondly, it was in the early days of Vue2, so it wouldn't be as useful today. But you already have a basic example in my answer. Does it matter if you call it `:schema` or `:formChildren`? If you're wondering how the form element interface should look like, it depends on what you want from your form(s). It typically has: `isDisabled, isValid, isPristine, type, component, children`+ any layout related prop(s) + `ìnitialValues` + overridable callbacks (most notably: `onSubmit`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what VueJS version you're on but for anyone trying to achieve this in Vue3, here's what the form component should look like:

```
<form>
  <template v-for="(component, index) in $slots.default?.()" :key="index">
    <div v-for="(child, i) in component.children" :key="i" class="mb-3">
      <component :is="child" />
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Had to figure it out while trying to add a wrapper around every slide in a carousel component and this worked for me.